# Button breaking page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'm still learning to become a junior front end and got following issue
if i press search button it breaks the page can figure out why.
https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX

Could you have a look?

```
function searchPokemon(){
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",`<div id="searchPokemonDiv"> ИТуц ыуфкс</div>`);
  let gotSearchPokemonDiv = document.getElementById("searchPokemonDiv");
  gotSearchPokemonDiv.innerHTML = `<form >
  <p>
    <label class="text">Search your pokemon</label><br>
    </p>
     <p>
    <label class="text">First name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
      <p>
    <button id="pokemonSearchButton">Search</button>
  </p>
  </form>
  <div id="divForPokemonSearchResult">
  img
  </div>
  `;
  document.getElementById("pokemonSearchButton").addEventListener("click",  showPokemonSearchResult);
 
}
 function showPokemonSearchResult(){
    // document.getElementById("divForPokemonSearchResult").innerHTML = "VOT I RESULTAT";
    console.log("push to start")
  }
```

Comment: The code in codepen is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in this line:

```
<button id="pokemonSearchButton">Search</button>
```

and it was fixed by adding `type="button"` to the same, i.e.

```
<button type="button" id="pokemonSearchButton">Search</button>
```